# Вывести дату в формате с сокращением названия месяца

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select to_char(last_updated_dtm,'dd-mm-yy')
```

Выводит дату в формате `14-01-20`, а нужно в формате `14-NOV-20`.

Подскажите, как это сделать?

Comment: https://oracleplsql.ru/to_char-function.html
`select to_char(last_updated_dtm,'dd-MON-yy')`

Comment: Для вашего примера никак. 01 это январь, что не меняй, ноябрём он не станет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выдержка из офф. документации [гл. Datetime Format Elements](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Format-Models.html#GUID-22F2B830-261E-4BF0-91FB-6A1DAFC6D0A3):

- `MON` - сокращённое название месяца
- `Mon` - тоже, но с первой заглавной буквой
- `mon` - тоже, но все прописные буквы

```sql
select to_char (date'2020-01-28', 'dd-MON-yy') dat from dual;
```

> 28-JAN-20